# PF commandbutton works locally but on deployed machine not calls action

Tags: tomcat, primefaces, cloudbees

I have issuing a very awkward problem with my jsf(spring&hibernate) application. 
I work on eclipse and localy my web app works perfectly but when it comes to deploying on remote server and running it login page display and connect to db successfully. 
however when i press login button nothing happens. in logs i see that it does not call login function. i use a free limited cloudbees tomcat7 server just to see how it seems before publish. i've also tried jboss server they served. What the problem can be? Does server version affect it?

Answer (score 0):

Server version for sure has impact on JSF. Try to run your application on same JBoss version. Tomcat7 is another subject, as it doesn't provide JSF you should be able to use your own provided implementation, assuming you embed the required JARs in your webapp.

Comment: tomcat 7 runs it perfectly, jboss is also works on local. but when it comes to deploy on cloudbees ui, db are ok except the action events. what can be the differences between local deploy and remote? if there would be an jar missing i should get noclass exception i guess.

Comment: Ok, it is about welcome page. my welcome page is Login.xhtml and it redirects domain here so i can see the Login.xhtml page but it does not function because (i think) server doesn't think it is actually Login.xhtml and does not register its functions so i give the full address in the browser by appending /Login.xhtml manually at the end. But is there a way to make it work with default welcome page?